# Creating ODBC Connection in WIX?

Tags: wix, odbc

I can't seem to find much information on this topic:

I want to create a basic connection with defined parameters (or maybe everything distinct besides perhaps what database) within an ODBC connection (32 bit).

I've scoured google and I can't seem to find any example within wix of creating a simple ODBC connection. (specifically an oracle connection)

Does this require a custom action (im new to Wix, and not super far into the tutorials/books) or is there a way for me to hardcode it into wix (bad practice I know, but just for practice)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a custom action for this. There is no other way of connecting a database with wix. Custom action is the only way.
To write a custom action try this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx